Add Blazor to an ASP.NET Core 8 project
I have an old project build with in ASP.NET Core 8 using Razor. Now, I want to slowly migrate this project to Blazor. The idea is to add Blazor in the project and migrate one page at the time from Razor pages to Blazor page and Blazor components.
In the Program.cs, I added those lines:
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

and then those lines
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.MapBlazorHub();

Also, I created a simple page for testing
@page "/Test"
<h3>@MyTest</h3>

@code {
    public string? MyTest = "Hello";
}

The application runs but the page Test is not found. If I have a Blazor component, I tried to add it to a page using
<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />

but it is not working. How can I add Blazor then?

Pretty sure you need routing setup in order for /Test to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing  also that component tag wont work with ServerSideBlazor, remove that, get your routing working first.

Take a look at this article.  It describes how to do it in Net6, but the process should be the same in Net8.  https://shauncurtis.github.io/Articles/Blazor-Brick-By-Brick.html
